# Are Berkeley cardinals easier to refute in ZFC than Reinhardt cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Kunen [showed](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Kunen_inconsistency) that [Reinhardt cardinals](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Reinhardt) are inconsistent in ZFC. But his proof is a bit technical for a non-set-theorist to follow. [Berkeley cardinals](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Berkeley) are stronger than Reinhardt cardinals. You can refute them in ZFC by observing that every Berkeley cardinal is Reinhardt, and then appealing to Kunen's theorem.

**Question 1:** Is there a more direct refutation of Berkeley cardinals in ZFC, perhaps one which might be more digestible by a non-set-theorist?

Recall that a definably-Berkeley cardinal is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that whenever $M$ is a transitive set with $\kappa \in M$, there are elementary embeddings $M \to M$ with arbitrarily large critical point $\alpha < \kappa$. A Reinhardt cardinal is when this holds for $M = V_\kappa$ (EDIT: In fact the "Reinhardt cardinal is defined to be the critical point of the embedding). So perhaps there is some other $M$ one can cook up which obviously fails the Berkeley property? Maybe $M = \kappa + 1$, for example?

(A Berkeley cardinal is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that whenver $M$ is a transitive set with $\kappa \in M$ and $A \subseteq M$, there are elementary embeddings $j : (M,A) \to (M,A)$ with arbitrarily large critical point below $\kappa$. Although it seems sometimes one restricts the definition to apply only when $M = V_\alpha$? I'm not sure if that's equivalent or weaker.)

**Question 2:** Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal (probably uncountable, regular, limit, measurable,etc.). Can it be the case in ZFC that there exists a nontrivial elementary embedding $\kappa + 1 \to \kappa + 1$?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that since $\kappa \not \in V_\kappa$, it's maybe not so clear why Berkeley cardinals are Reinhardt...

Comment: Is your question 2 really just asking about elementary embeddings between ordinals? If so, the answer is yes, $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably there are lots of nontrivial elementary embeddings from $\kappa+1$ to itself whenever $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal. Basically, ordinals by themselves have very little expressive power (although things get more interesting if we move up from FOL, see [this old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378918/can-ord-have-nontrivial-second-order-elementary-self-embeddings)).

Comment: Berkeley cardinals are not Reinhardt cardinals as $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves the least Berkeley cardinal is singular but every Reinhardt cardinal must be regular. However, if $\delta$ is a Berkeley cardinal, then there is $\lambda<\delta$ such that $(V_\lambda, V_{\lambda+1})$ is a model of $\mathsf{NGB}$ with a Reinhardt cardinal, which becomes a model of choice if we work over $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: Another question in this vein one could ask is whether you can write down a large cardinal notion not known to be inconsistent with ZF with an 'immediate' proof of inconsistency with ZFC. (Obviously this is a somewhat vague question.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Thanks, that's clarifying. Do you know what is the status of the assertion "There is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that for any transitive $M$ with $\kappa \subseteq M$ there are elementary embeddings $M \to M$ with arbitrarily large critical point $\alpha < \kappa$"? This sort of $\kappa$ would be manifestly Reinhardt, and it also implies that $\kappa$ is Berkeley...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, that answers Question 2! From [this MSE answer of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947955/consistency-of-non-trivial-elementary-embedding-j-ord-to-ord) I learned that every ordinal is elementarily equivalent to an ordinal $< \omega^\omega \cdot 2$, and that $Ord$ is elementarily equivalent to $\omega^\omega \cdot 2$. Do you know whether one can explicitly classify the complete first-order theories of ordinals?

Comment: See slide 9 of https://math.berkeley.edu/~goldberg/Slides/EvenOrdinalsAndTheKunenInconsistency.pdf. It gives a pretty digestible argument (imo) that Berkeley cardinals are incompatible with AC. Although, it does rely on an alternative (equivalent) characterization with ranks instead of transitive sets.

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, this is done in Rosenstein's book [*Linear orderings*](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-orderings-Pure-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0125976801) which is excellent but out of print. The theory of an ordinal can be read off of its Cantor normal form.

Comment: @TimCampion I have no idea, unfortunately.

Comment: Tim, towards the question addressed to @Hanul, if $\kappa\in M$, then this is the definition of Berkeley. If not, then $M\{\kappa\}$ is transitive again, so by the definition of Berkeley we get embeddings. All we need to note that in this case it must be that $j(\kappa)=\kappa$ when $j:M\to M$ is an elementary embedding, since $\kappa$ is the largest ordinal in $M\cup\{\kappa\}$ in that case.

Comment: @KeithMillar I should have said in my slides that this argument is due to Woodin.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm confused -- your argument seems to say that every Berkeley cardinal satisfies the stronger axiom I stated, which in particular means that every Berkeley cardinal is Reinhardt. But Hanul explained that the smallest Berkeley cardinal can't be Reinhardt...

Comment: @TimCampion I think you are using a different definition of Reinhardt than the standard one. Typically, a cardinal is Reinhardt if it is the critical point of an elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$. But as far as I can tell from the comments, you seem to be calling a cardinal $\lambda$ Reinhardt if there is an elementary embedding from $V_\lambda$ to $V_\lambda$. Does this clear up the confusion?

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Yes, thanks -- that helps!

Comment: @TimCampion By the way, the two versions of Berkeley are equivalent (since you can take $\alpha = \text{rank}(M)$ and then code $M$ into $A$).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is easier to refute Berkeleys than Reinhardts. There is a very simple refutation of Berkeleys in ZFC that is due to Woodin. It is part of the motivation for his contention that Berkeley cardinals should be inconsistent with ZF.

Towards a contradiction, assume ZFC plus $\delta$ is the least Berkeley. For each $\alpha< \delta$, choose a transitive set $M_\alpha$ containing $\delta$ such that there is no $j:M_\alpha \to M_\alpha$ with critical point less than $\alpha$. Let $\gamma$ be the supremum  of the ranks of the $M_\alpha$. Since $\delta$ is Berkeley there is an elementary $i : V_{\gamma+1} \to V_{\gamma+1}$ with critical point below $\delta$ such that $i(\vec M) = \vec M$. Notice that $i$ has no fixed points $\alpha$ between its critical point and $\delta$. Otherwise $i(M_\alpha) = M_\alpha$, but then $i\restriction M_\alpha$ is an elementary embedding from $M_\alpha$ to $M_\alpha$ with critical point less than $\alpha$.

Therefore $\delta$ has countable cofinality: in fact, $\delta = \sup_{n<\omega} \kappa_n$ where $\kappa_n = i^n(\kappa)$. But applying Berkeliness again, we can get another embedding $k: V_{\gamma+1} \to V_{\gamma+1}$ with critical point below $\delta$ such that $k(\vec N) = \vec N$ where $N_n = M_{\kappa_n}$. Clearly $k$ fixes each $N_n$ (since $k(n) = n$). But taking $n$ large enough that $\kappa_n > \text{crit}(k)$, $k\restriction N_n$ is an elementary embedding that contradicts the definition of $M_{\kappa_n}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Does $\vec M$ denote (the graph of) the function $\delta \to V$, $\alpha \mapsto M_\alpha$? Also, does $i(M_\alpha)$ really mean $i(M_\alpha)$, or does it mean the image of $i$ restricted to $M_\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, $\vec M$ is what you guessed. But $i(M_\alpha)$ really means $i(M_\alpha)$!!! Of course since $i(\vec M) = \vec M$, we have $i(M_\alpha)= M_{i(\alpha)}$.

Comment: Thanks! A few notes and questions. (1) In the second sentence, the condition is that there is no elementary embedding $j : M_\alpha \to M_\alpha$ with critical point below $\alpha$. (2) In order to have $\vec M \in V_{\gamma+1}$, we need $\gamma$ to be a limit ordinal -- otherwise we only have $\vec M \in V_{\gamma+3}$ or something like that. I see that the $M_\alpha$ can't be constant in $\alpha$ because $\delta$ is Berkeley, which feels close to implying $\gamma$ is limit, but I don't quite see it.

Comment: (3) In the second sentence, we used that there is no definably-Berkeley below $\delta$, but then in the fourth sentence, used that $\delta$ is in fact Berkeley. (4) In the last sentence of the first paragraph, I don't see why $i$ would restrict to an elementary embedding $M_\alpha \to M_\alpha$. I know this would hold if $M_\alpha$ were an elementary substructure of $V_{\gamma+1}$, but I don't think it is.

Comment: (5) In the first sentence of the second paragraph, I think $j$ is $i$? (6) In the first sentence of the second paragraph, the point is that $n \mapsto \kappa_n$ is definable in $V_{\gamma+1}$ by the recursion theorem there, and then the sup is also definable, so $i$ preserves the sup, and hence the sup is a fixed point of $i$. (7) Similarly to before, I don't understand why $k$ restricts to an elementary embedding $N_n \to N_n$.

Comment: (8) Where did we use choice?

Comment: @TimCampion Choice is being used in the step where we choose the sequence of $M_\alpha$'s uniformly.

Comment: (2) Well, you can make $\gamma$ as big as you want. Depending on how you code the sequence of $M_\alpha$'s, the $\gamma$ I chose will work. But you could go up $\omega$ ranks and never worry about a pairing function again. (3) I'm not sure what you mean about definably Berkeley, $M_\alpha$ isn't definable. (4) If $i(M_\alpha) = M_\alpha$ then $i\restriction M_\alpha$ is elementary from $M_\alpha$ to $M_\alpha$ since the $M_\alpha\vDash \varphi(a)$ if and only if $V_{\gamma+1}$ satisfies the relativization $\varphi^{M_\alpha}(a)$ iff it satisfies $\varphi^{M_\alpha}(i(a))$.

Comment: (6) Well it may not be definable, but $\vec \kappa$ is in $V_{\gamma+1}$ and $i(\vec \kappa) = \vec \kappa\restriction \mathbb N^+$ (roughly), so $i(\sup \vec \kappa) = \sup (\vec \kappa\restriction \mathbb N^+) = \sup \vec \kappa$.

Comment: @Gabe "(roughly)" 